# Vue deleting DOM node in created live-cycle hook to initialize a component

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm currently trying to understand why [this](https://codepen.io/giggo1604/pen/NXgBxZ) example is not working as expected. So what I'm trying to achieve is to initialize my `ContentView` with the server side rendered HTML present in the DOM. Therefore I intend to check if `init__main-content` exists to then initialize the component with the innerHTML. Afterwards I simply tried to delete the initial node but this is not working and I end up with the content shown twice.

There must be some vue "magic" I'm not aware of, can please someone explain this behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess there is problem in your code as you are using `created` hook insted you can use `mounted` hook.

so after `mounting` `vue` does finish all its magic to `dom` and now your changes can be persisted in to the dom.

if you use `created` then `vue` may be using that inner html as template and rewrite it it to `dom` thinking that previous html is not matching with current html when instance is created. as you already removing that element. so it will try to make it correct and add previous html again to maintain `virtual-dom` and `real-dom` changes.

if you use `mounted` hook your application is working fine try it.